# Replacing the "millionaire" tag with "who-wants-to-be-a-millionaire"

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Can someone please link https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/millionaire and https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/who-wants-to-be-a-millionaire ?

Maybe `millionaire` should be replaced by `who-wants-to-be-a-millionaire`, in case someone wants to ask a question about a movie or TV series called "Millionaire"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good idea. I have merged the tags.